# How to post json array inside json object in Android

Tags: java, android, arrays, json

I wanna send my data to web service. But i can't send

```
{ "OrgID":"1",
"UserDepartment":"1", 
"WorkType":"1977", 
"WorkDefinition":"EXAMPLE_EXAMPLE", 
"Confirmed":[
             {  "Confirmed":"qaAgo/+/j/XhECIhlAo2SQ==",
                "Confirmed":"PJNd6u9RwTIwM4SRrom+mQ==",
                "Confirmed":"75qFEZ7bnq+kCFvLS625Ww=="}], 
"FileName":"", 
"FileMimeType":"", 
"FileContent":"" 
}
```

i can send all data except "Confirmed".

My Java codes here..

```
public static void sendParameter(String organizationId, String departmentId, String workType, String comfirmedList, String fileName, String fileMimeType, String fileContent, String definition) {

        parameterList = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        parameterList.add(new BasicNameValuePair("OrgID", organizationId));
        parameterList.add(new BasicNameValuePair("UserDepartment", departmentId));
        parameterList.add(new BasicNameValuePair("WorkType", workType));
        parameterList.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Confirmed", comfirmedList));
        parameterList.add(new BasicNameValuePair("FileName", fileName));
        parameterList.add(new BasicNameValuePair("FileMimeType", fileMimeType));
        parameterList.add(new BasicNameValuePair("FileContent", fileContent));
        parameterList.add(new BasicNameValuePair("WorkDefinition", definition));
    }
```

How can i send Confirmed datas?

Comment: What is the exact problem? Show the call to the server with the payload and the error message.

Comment: {
  "Result": false,
  "ResultText": "ORA-01722: geçersiz sayı\nORA-02063: önceki line, kaynağı ISISTEMDB"
}

Answer (score 0):

You can manually format the data as json string and sent the json string as entity to the request. On the server side make sure you have a Class that matches the exact structure.
Example

```
    String paramString = "{\"OrgID\":\"" + OrgID
            +"\",\"UserDepartment\":\"" + UserDepartment
            +"\",\"WorkType\":\"" + WorkType+ "\"}";
    HttpEntity httpEntity = null;
    try {
        httpEntity = new StringEntity(paramString);
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
    httpPost.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    httpPost.setEntity(entity);
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

So sorry, my json must be

```
    { "OrgID":"1",
    "UserDepartment":"1", 
    "WorkType":"1977", 
    "WorkDefinition":"EXAMPLE_EXAMPLE", 
    "Confirmed":[ 
                   {"Confirmed":"qaAgo/+/j/XhECIhlAo2SQ==,}
                   {"Confirmed":"qaAgo/+/j/XhECIhlAo2SQ=="}], 
    "FileName":"", 
    "FileMimeType":"", 
    "FileContent":"" 
    }
```